# Using LiveData instead of callback hell to interact between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-livedata

Long time ago the normal and suggested way on how to communicate between fragments were to create a interface that was extended in Activity. Basically, if I wanted to get data from Fragment B to Fragment C, I had to do Fragment B to MainActivity and then MainActivity to Fragment C. In my view - total mess.

Just started to use `LiveData` and thought of using it instead of callbacks - for instance:

**FragmentInteraction.kt**

```
val onOkayButtonClicked = SingleLiveEvent<Void>()
val onCancelButtonClicked = SingleLiveEvent<Void>()
```

**FragmentA.kt**

```
onOkayButtonClicked.call()
```

**FragmentB.kt**

```
onOkayButtonClicked.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    // do whatever u want
})
```

Does this approach has any down-sides? Is there an easier / more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: Check https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dz1q3f/askandroid_at_android_dev_summit_2019/

Answer (score 0):

You could have only one ViewModel(lifecycleOwner = activity), that would have all the liveDataEvents you need for the interactions. You will act on the liveData from the onClick events:

```
okayButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onOkayButtonClicked() }
```

This LiveData will be observed by the NavigationComponent, or similar you are using for handling fragment transactions, and it will do the transitions for you.

All these transitions I recommend doing them on the Activity level.

Comment: In normal scenerio - yes, but in my case, I've a Big fragment (container), that holds smaller part of view that is also fragment (fragment inside fragment). The smallest fragment is changed a lot.